# How to set checkboxes in Recyclerview when user exits application and returns? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

**I am currently using SharedPreferences key, value pairs to save the state, but can't seem to read from the prefs file and check the boxes.**

I have written this self-explanatory code. However, a NullPointerException is thrown in the line `list.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.performClick();`. I just want to know how to set the checkboxes in Recyclerview list to checked and save that state. Please help.

```
btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Number number : numbers) {
            if (number.isSelected()) {
                if (stringBuilder.length() > 0)
                    stringBuilder.append(", ");
                stringBuilder.append(number.getTextONEs());
                Log.e("Checked", "here");
                setPreference(getApplicationContext(), "1", number.getONEs());
            } else {
                Log.e("Not checked", "here");
                setPreference(getApplicationContext(), "0", number.getONEs());
            }
        }
    }
});
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < tocArray.length; i++) {
        String value = getPreference(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(i));
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            list.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.performClick();
        } else {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is from the holder of the Recyclerview;

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindData(numbers.get(position));

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        holder.checkbox.setChecked(numbers.get(position).isSelected());

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                numbers.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });
```

Can you also please explain this whole concept of recyclerview and cards and why the "holder" is needed? Thanks. Please help!
Regards

Comment: Where is `numbers` ?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. It returns strings using the methods shown in the code. My question is how to save the state of these boxes and check them later when the user returns to the activity.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a perfectly good question, and can't find a solution on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try add these methods to your Activity:

```
private void restoreSelectedPositions(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("selected_pos", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int tmpTotal = preferences.getInt("total_pos", 0);
    if(tmpTotal == numbers.size()){
        for(int i=0; i<tmpTotal; i++{
            boolean tmpFlag = preferences.getBoolean("pos" + i, false);
            numbers.get(i).setSelected(tmpFlag);
        }
    }else{
        // Saved data size not match with existing data.
    }
}

private void saveSelectedPositions(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("selected_pos", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putInt("total_pos", numbers.size());
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
        editor.putBoolean("pos" + i, numbers.get(i).isSelected());
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Change onResume() of Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    restoreSelectedPositions();
    // Change the line below.
    Your RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When you need to save, just call saveSelectedPositions(). Hope this help!